# Can't Print anything With Spaces in Java. Only First Word gets Printed others are Skipped

Tags: java

Can't Print anything With Spaces in Java. Only First Word gets Printed others are Skipped.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter the Limit: \n");
        Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
        int limit = Integer.parseInt(S.nextLine());
        System.out.println("WORD ? \n");
        String Word = S.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            System.out.println(Word);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you check out the documentation for the version of java you are using. For example, java 10 Scanner class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Java naming conventions have methods and variables start with a lower case letter. (S should be s.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in for loop you always print "Word" variable and later you do not change it. You should add this row inside the loop: `Word = S.next();`

Answer (score 0):

That is because `String Word = S.next();` is expecting an input and `System.out.println("WORD ? \n");` is just printing the string.

To resolve this just remove those two lines of code and replace it with a string variable `String Word = "WORD ? \n";`